# How to send Powershell 2.0 email across any version of Windows Server?

Tags: email, powershell, smtp, exchange-server

I do apologize in advance. I am a programmer, but have only been working with Powershell, Exchange, and Windows Server for the past few days.

I am using the following code to send an email to all servers on a domain. When testing against my domain, every server successfully sends the email.

```
$EmailFrom = "test@cscncoc.com"
$EmailTo = "bjackson@csncoc.com" 
$Subject = "Test mail Subject"
$Body = "Test Email Body" 
$SMTPServer = "AFSBS2K11" 
$SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, 25) 
$SMTPClient.Send($EmailFrom, $EmailTo, $Subject, $Body)
```

However, when testing against an external domain, only one or two servers send an email to, out of ~8 servers. I am using our SMTP server and have tested Telnet against port 25 successfully. I have looked through all sorts of examples and questions and usually it doesn't work at all for them, but I am getting success on some of the servers. The error I receive is "Failure sending mail". Just in case it matters, the servers are running different versions of Server (2K8, 2K3, SBS, etc.) and all have at least PS v2.0. I have also tried the Send-MailMessage cmdlet.

Comment: Have you tried doing a manual telnet from one of the failing servers to the smtp server to see what the failure code/response is in the smtp conversation?

Comment: Have you tried using the fully-qualified domain name of the SMTP server? How about the `send-mailmessage` cmdlet instead of `SmtpClient`?

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion @mjolinor , I will attempt to get remote access so I can Telent.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, in part due to @mjolinor . I Telnet against port 25 from the server and was unsuccessful. This all made total sense because port 25 was open internally for our domain. I opened up port 26 for incoming connections, performed a Telnet operation, and it works flawlessly!